# Time-enable a WFS to use on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, wfs, time, date

Is it possible to time-enable a WFS with a date field properly coded as DATE in ArcGIS Online to use with the new timeline widget in Experience? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the broad steps, sorry I am not including detailed examples for each, but I will include references to the ESRI documentation (for what it's worth.)

1. In Arcgis Pro, time-enable your featureclass as in [this tutorial example](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/get-started/visualize-temporal-data.htm).
2. In Arcgis Pro, reveal the [`timeline slider`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/time/visualize-temporal-data-using-the-time-slider.htm) and test the functionality of your data before publishing.
3. In Arcgis Pro, publish the time-enabled featureclass to Arcgis Online.
4. In Arcgis Online, manage the layer and ensure a single timezone is selected as a default for the layer as demonstrated in [this blog post](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/working-with-agol-feature-services-date-time-attributes-in-non-utc-time-zone-in-arcgis-pro-2-7/).
5. Start a new Arcgis Pro project, add the AGOL layer to it, and again test the `timeline slider` on the online layer.
6. If all of the above worked, then upgrade to the latest Experience Builder, build a small test application, and test the [`Timeline Widget`](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/latest/configure-widgets/widgets-overview.htm) using the AGOL source layer.